# form validation and show error message without ts file

Tags: validation, angular, ionic2

is there any possibility to get error message without ts file, I used this i could validate my input

```
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(form)" novalidate>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label style="color: black;" fixed>User Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" name="username" placeholder="valid user name" [(ngModel)]="username"  pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3}" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label style="color: black;"  fixed>Email Id</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Examples@gmail.com" [(ngModel)]="email"
            pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <button ion-button type="submit" value="Submit" block>Login</button>
    </form>
     <p *ngIf=username.valid>  The following problems have been found with the username: </p>
```

what i need is to display error message if the input is not valid, and i should not submit empty form

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
    } 
logForm(form) {
        console.log(form.value)

        if(form.valid) {
            console.log(form.value);
            /*here i get user entered values as object*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using this `*ngIf= "username.valid"` and then try use dobule quation in ngIf

Comment: actually i am getting err when i use valid inside <p> tag "runtime err could not find 'valid' " is the err i am getting after build gets completed.

Comment: you have to use this `*ngIf = "ngForm.controls.username.valid"` update your question with .ts file code so that may help you

Comment: Kindly read my question once

Comment: i understood you want only template driven approach but both template driven approach or data driven approach you have to import something with @forms supporting library and also if you are not able to console log `#form="ngForm"` this i mean ngForm variable then how can we know the object structure of value to access the required input field

Comment: we dont need ts file i think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your form attributes something that will identify what fields we're going to validate, so for username, let's say this:

```
#userName="ngModel"
```

You can loose the `[(ngModel)]` in this case.

and then your validation:

```
<div *ngIf="userName.errors?.required && userName.touched">
  Name is required
</div>
<div *ngIf="userName.errors?.pattern && userName.touched">
  Not valid
</div>
```

So you just use the different validations you have set for input and check whether they match the validations, e.g `required`, `pattern` with the prefix of the name of the form control and `errors?`

So here's how your username validation would look like:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label style="color: black;" fixed>User Name</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" name="username" ngModel #userName="ngModel" 
    required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div *ngIf="userName.errors?.required && userName.touched">
   Name is required
</div>
<div *ngIf="userName.errors?.pattern && userName.touched">
  Not valid
</div>
```

Here's a [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBlACophgaADep56by8G?p=preview).

Comment: Ya its not working with ionic i get err stating that "cannot read the property of error? undefined" @AJT_82

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, see my updated answer, where also the plunker is now ionic. Hmmh. Could you provide a plunker that recreates this issue?

Comment: Only thing I can think of then is that you are using some version of Ionic, which doesn't support this.

Comment: It often is just a small tweak needed! :) You are welcome, glad I could help!